# Google play games sign in error on android

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have created a game on android by using libgdx library. I implemented google play services for sign in and showing leaderboards. On Android Studio, both of them work perfectly. I can log in my test account and I can see leaderboards. But when I update the game on google play, and update it on my smartphone, I can not log in my play games account.

It says, "Connecting to Play Games", then I choose my account and then nothing happens. Still loading and eventually disappears. When I open game again, same scenario happens again.

I did the same coding that shows how to implement google play services to your game guidances.

What can I do? Thanks from now.

EDIT:

I have changed SHA-1 key and it worked. You can find on Google Play Console under Release->Setup->App Integrity. Select App signing key certificate SHA-1. And update yours from Play Games services->Setup and Management->Configuration then select your app. You will see Authorisation, add it to ther by creating OAuth client or update the current one.